# jQuery DatePicker: Get Selected Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to be able to grab the selected date from the Datepicker and populate another textbox with the selected value. I am currently using the `onClose` function like this:

```
$('#defaultDate').datepicker({
    onClose:function(theDate) {
        $('#txtEntry1').text = theDate;
    }
});
```

Comment: And what? What's your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an easier way to do it. Use the built-in [alt-field option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field) and you're done.

> Populate an alternate field with its own date format whenever a date
>   is selected using the **altField** and **altFormat** options. This feature
>   could be used to present a human-friendly date for user selection,
>   while passing a more computer-friendly date through for further
>   processing.

Comment: Please note: the alt-field option doesn't work for spans (probably other html elements as well)

Comment: @NathanKoop well... _yeah_, a `<span>` is not a form field.

Comment: I didn't notice any qualifiers (I guess "field" should be somewhat of a clue) I just wanted to populate a span elsewhere on the form based on this input. Making a readonly textbox isn't really a great solution in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked through the docs? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#events

**onSelect function(dateText, inst)**

Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the onSelect event as an init option.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```