# jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've looked at a few question on here and online but i cant seem to find the answer im looking for or maybe i just cant implement it right. I have 2 datepickers...a check in date and a check out date. The check out date must always be within 30 days of the check in date. I've managed to use the code below to get this result however its on an onSelect therefore it dosent work when the page is loaded, only when u select a check in date. By default the check in date is today therefore the check out should only be selectable for up to 30 days from when the page loads. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
$(function(){$( "#datepicker, #departure" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: +1,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+12m',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: 'http://images.aboutrooms.com/hotels/graphics/calendar.gif',
    //beforeShowDay: function(date){return [date.getTime() != today.getTime(), ''];}
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        if(this.id == 'datepicker'){
          var dateMin = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
          var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); // Min Date = Selected + 1d
          var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 31); // Max Date = Selected + 31d
          $('#departure').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);
          $('#departure').datepicker("option","maxDate",rMax);                    
        }

    }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this:

- move that `onSelect` function to external function
- make call on it when `$(document).ready();`
- point to it from `onSelect` in `datepicker` configuration object

fn:

```
function datepickerhandle( selectedDate ) {
        if(this.id == 'datepicker'){
          var dateMin = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
          var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); // Min Date = Selected + 1d
          var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 31); // Max Date = Selected + 31d
          $('#departure').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);
          $('#departure').datepicker("option","maxDate",rMax);                    
        }

    }
```

onSelect:

```
onSelect: datepickerhandle,
```

onLoad:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ datepickerhandle([selected time]); });
```

to get selected time see this SO question: [jQuery DatePicker: Get Selected Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311608/jquery-datepicker-get-selected-date)

---

**variant no. 2**

[jQuery datepicker set selected date, on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606463/jquery-datepicker-set-selected-date-on-the-fly)

when document loads, set the date for datepicker instance on-fly to fire onSelected event

Comment: Thanks for the response. just having troubles with the call. I'm guessing its to do with the selected time but I dont quiet understand it. If I just do datepickerhandle(); it just works as I had it initially. Any chance you can help me with that selected time.

Comment: use alternative field, which can be hidden http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field

Answer (score 0):

simply update field with end of date picker initialization like this

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date()).trigger('change')
```